# Fastest way to check whether a file contains any string from a list of strings

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have several .tgz log files each containing few hundred to thousand lines. I also have a list of error strings. I have to read each and every log file inside the zip file and check whether any of the error strings is present in that file. I also need to get the name of the file in which the error pattern was found.

```
errorList = ["errorPattern1", "errorPattern2",..., "errorPatternN"]
```

Which is the fastest way to do it in Python?

Comment: Are they tgz files, or just gzipped? If it's the latter, you may benefit from calling `zgrep` on your data. If your patterns aren't too complex, you could build and call a command like `['grep', '('+'|'.join(errorlist)+')'] + filelist`.

Comment: The [`tarfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html) module automatically handles gzip (or bz2) compression. You should be able to do what you want using that module and the `re` module.

Comment: Depending on how many error patterns you have, you might get a slight performance improvement if you order your patterns (assuming you use re `|` alternation) with the most common error first (on the left).

Comment: Why do it with python? Why not just use grep? It's way more intelligent about searching than you are going to be in the time you want to do this task.

Comment: @Greg Plus OP could even call grep using python

Answer (score 2):

Nested loops iterating over the '.tgz' files in the directory and over the items in each tarfile.  Read the text of the entire file object at once.  Then check if any of the error patterns are in the text.

Something like this:

```
import glob, tarfile

for fname in glob.iglob('*.tgz'):
    with tarfile.open('filename', 'rb') as tar:

        for info in iter(tar.next, None):
            text = tar.extractfile(info).read()

            if any(msg in text for msg in error_list):
                print "an error message was found in: ", info.name
```